# How can I solve Android AVD GPU Driver Issue error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

today I was testing an app on the android emulator, I was tired to use the onscreen keyboard so I edited the device and enabled keyboard support, the next time I started the emulator I got this error:

[image: this error]

and it stopped working

I tried switching between the various gpu mode and starting the amulator from command line forcing it to use host gpu but nothing worked. 
anyone know a way to solve this?